# Using arrays and table names for unique value list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am building a summary tab in an excel workbook that is linked to numerous other workbooks to track hierarchical business data (ie. Numerous files for subordinate teams exchanging data with a master workbook that tracks them all). To make it easier and to increase uniformity, I'm using tables for all of the data and "building" table names based on each spreadsheet's specific criteria -- then using `INDIRECT` to bring the table references to life and complete my calculations.

To simplify the formulas I'm using, I've been using arrays to check all tables at once for pieces of data. For example, I've built a table for subordinate units (Ref_Units) which contains the units' names: ABC, EFG, XYZ. I then have a table (Ref_Tables) translate my Ref_Units into standardized table names. Formula is something like `{=Ref_Units&"_2016_Sales_Rpt"}`. Now I can make some `SUMIFS` using Ref_Tables that look in several different locations for data -- and to make updates, I only have to change Ref_Units.

My Summary tab will be the culmination of data coming from a dozen+ tables and upwards to 10 workbooks. The basis of the summaries are gathered from drop down lists specifying categories and years being summarized; these values are plugged into some INDIRECT formulas to generate table names and voila.

Now, the problem: let's say each unit records sales numbers and projections for specific items like "televisions", "stereos", "flatware", "candles", etc. and each of these items has also has a category accompanying it: "Electronics","Homewares", "Decor", etc.

I want a summary spanning all of the units' data pulling the numbers in each category (I should note that categories may change each month, so the list must be dynamic). To make the list dynamic (and to give myself the ability to summarize based on other criteria), I am using a formula I found online to generate a list of unique/distinct values.

Right now, I'm using `INDEX/MATCH` and `COUNTIF` to generate a unique list of categories. So, my unique list starts in cell C9 and the formula looks something like this:

```
{=iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(Ref_Tables&"[Category]"), MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$8:C8, Ref_Tables&"[Category]"), 0)),"")}
```

This function will not work. The only way I can get the desired results is to input multiple iterations of the formula, each using a single table name from Ref_Tables and joined with &.

Example:

```
{=iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT("ABC_2016_Sales_Report"&"[Category]"), MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$8:C8, "ABC_2016_Sales_Report"&"[Category]"), 0)),"")&iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT("EFG_2016_Sales_Report"&"[Category]"), MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$8:C8, "EFG_2016_Sales_Report"&"[Category]"), 0)),"")&iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT("XYZ_2016_Sales_Report"&"[Category]"), MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$8:C8, "XYZ_2016_Sales_Report"&"[Category]"), 0)),"")}
```

**Remark: the look up arrays are strangely input here because they are actually cell references pulling in table name and column name being looked up, then brought to life with `INDIRECT`

Partially my problem is that the resulting formula is about 10 lines long which looks horrible, but it also looks too confusing to anyone using the workbook.

Is there any way to get the `INDEX/MATCH` to look at multiple tables for generate the list that is more concise?

I should note that my boss refuses to use VBA/macros/pivot tables because there are not many in my office skilled enough to troubleshoot issues in these areas. Help?

Comment: Too much information. Just provide a small set of sample data, and the outcome you currently have with the formula you use, and the expected outcome you want to have for it.

Comment: Your boss might save time and money by training more people in VBA.  Troubleshooting complex formula issues can be much more difficult than troubleshooting well-documented VBA.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could pare down the question and still be specific enough to illustrate the problem. Sorry.